# Node Application test via jest and supertest keep failing

Tags: node.js, express, npm, jestjs, supertest

I have a MERN stack application that I am running a test on using `jest` and `supertest`. I am new to testing and was following a tutorial. However, mine keep failing. My MERN stack application has redis database instance for storing users' `refresh token`. It also uses `node crone` to carry out scheduled background tasks.
I am getting these errors when I ran my tests:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

And this error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

 This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. 
 Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I have used `npm test --detectOpenHandles` to see if I could detect the asynchronous operations but I didnt see any. Like, it wasn't revealed.

Here is my test:
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')

```
 describe('Test POST /register', ()=>{


  test('It should respond with 200 success', async ()=>{
    const response = await request(app).post('/register');
    
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    
    
   },);

   test('It should catch password must be present', ()=>{});

  })
```

I have tried adding this line of code to the test:

```
afterAll(async () => { await app.close(); });
```

It didn't resolve it. I have also tried adding `done()`, it didn't work too. I have also increased the timeOut which I added as second argument in `test`, still the same thing.

I am testing my routes and here is the current one I tried which is `register` route.

```
router.post('/register', register);
```

Here is the `app.js` file

```
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/users",userRoute);


 app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 })

 app.use(checkDB);


 module.exports = app;
```

Here is the `server.js`

```
 const http = require('http');
 require('dotenv').config();;//declaring the envy file

 const app = require('./app');
 //mongoDb
 const connectDB = require('./db/connect');

 const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


const server = http.createServer(app);


 const start = async () => {
 try {
 await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL)
 server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
  );
 } catch (error) {
console.log(error);
 }
};

 start();
```

Comment: If you start the app without tests - does it work?

Comment: Also, in the test you do POST request. Not sure if it's intentional

Comment: Yes. Works and I even deployed and still working both locally and on the cloud.

Comment: That was how the tutorial wrote it. Is it not supposed to be so? The register route is actually making a post request

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz Can you post the code where you import and initialize `supertest` and the `register` function?

Comment: supertest was imported inside the test file this way: const request = require('supertest'). As for the function code for registration, it is a bit long. Do u mind I send it to you via message?